# HTML/CSS: Boostrap3 div placement with 2 on left, 1 on right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I have three `div`s on my page and I want them to be placed with two smaller `div`s on the left and a bigger `div` on the right (see picture).  Right now, the third `div` is being placed on a different row, below the second div.

How can I move that third `div` up?

PS- The `div`s can be rearranged if necessary.  I just want the two smaller ones on the left and the larger one on the right.

[image: div placement]

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Larf3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>DIV 1
            </h2>
        <form class="form-income form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/profile/update">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="paycheck" class="control-label col-sm-3">Paycheck/Salary</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paycheck" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="investments" class="control-label col-sm-3">Investments</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="investments" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="otherIncome" class="control-label col-sm-3">Other</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="otherIncome" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="update-income" type="submit" >Update</button>
    <div class="resultsIncome"></div>
</form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>DIV 2
            </h2>
        <form class="form-expenses form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/profile/update">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Rent/Mortgage</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Utilities</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Groceries</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Automobile</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Loans/Debt</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Credit Card</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Insurance</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Personal Care</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Entertainment</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Other</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="update-expenses" type="submit">Update</button>
    <div class="resultsExpenses"></div>
</form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>DIV 3
            </h2>
        <form class="form-income form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/profile/update">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="paycheck" class="control-label col-sm-3">Paycheck/Salary</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paycheck" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="investments" class="control-label col-sm-3">Investments</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="investments" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="otherIncome" class="control-label col-sm-3">Other</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="otherIncome" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="update-income" type="submit" >Update</button>
    <div class="resultsIncome"></div>
</form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put DIV1 and DIV3 in the first column like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="content">
      DIV1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      DIV3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="content">
      DIV2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an update of your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/Larf3/1/

Comment: OF COURSE!! It was right under my nose.  Thanks!  And by DIV1 and DIV2 I assume you actually mean DIV1 and DIV3.